# Visual Studio Code view command run by last input

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to figure out which editor command is used when I press keys in different contexts. For example, I want to know which editor command is run when I press DownArrow while the quick fix widget is open, as shown:

[image: VS Code quick fix widget]

How can I find out which command is run when I press a key in VS Code? The Keyboard Shortcuts search-by-key capability does not solve my problem.